# Flip in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm making use of Viewpager in my application.. when the user swipes left or right, I'll show next or previous image - basically a slideshow (of images) kind of app..

If the user taps on the app, I want to flip a view in ViewPager.. a view behind every single view - user must be able to flip the view when he taps on it.

This is the code,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    .... <some code> ....

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_viewpager);

    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener((OnPageChangeListener) pageListener);

    final GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapGestureListener());

    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
              return false;
         }
    });
}

private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

    // HERE I CAPTURED SINGLE TAP.. HOW DO I CHANGE THE VIEW OF VIEWPAGER?  
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set onTouchEvent to the View inside the page, not to the whole viewpager.
In the ImageViewPagerAdapter, you have

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
```

when create the view, I assume an ImageView, set the onTouchListener to it so you have a reference to the view that can be touched.

For the flipping itself take a look at [this example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/flip-view-example/), it's very clear.

**EDIT:**

here an example I copy pasted from an app I made, I cut off the actual code inside the onclicklistener because it was quite long and not relevant. I used this method because inside istantiateItem() you create the view you want to attach the listener to.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    Log.e("InstantiateItem",Integer.toString(position));
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

      imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);

      imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
             // do some stuf when clicked...to see if it works you could try
             Log.e("Click on image",Integer.toString(position));
          }
      });
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

      return imageView;

}
```

Comment: I tried setting onTouchListener for the ImageView, but is working out. Can you please post some code or point some working examples?

Comment: @Naveen no luck with this method?

Comment: sorry somehow missed this thread. will give it a try today and let you know.. thanks!!